# FLS/CRUD Enforcement In Helper Classes

Tags: apex, security-review, field-level-security, fls, crud

We have several controller classes that call out to helper classes to grab data or save data. This has resulted in a few questions...

1. Is it sufficient to simply check all permissions in the constructor to show a permissions error before the user gets to the point of querying data or saving data. To me, this seems more user friendly than waiting for a specific button click to show a permissions error. If its advisable to check in each helper method, how would everyone recommend handling an access error? Throw an exception and catch it in the controller to display a message on screen?

   ```
   public with sharing class ExampleController
   {
       public ExampleController()
       {
           if(Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isAccessible())
           {
               ContactHelper.getContact();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Insufficient access.'));
       }
   }


   public with sharing class ContactHelper
   {

       public static Contact getContact()
       {
           return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact];
       } 
   }
   ```
2. A similar question to the above but to do with triggers. If our trigger calls a handler which updates a related record that a user may or may not have permissions to see, how should this be handled?

Comment: N.B. - the Force.com Enterprise Architecture (fflib) pattern on GitHub/trailhead does this automatically for you

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for sending that. The frustration is that our app has approximately 800 lines of code and around 3-4 DML and 3-4 queries. Adding these enterprise libraries seems overkill for such a small lightweight application. I suppose everyone would have their own angle on that... What I could do is strip out just the CRUD/FLS parts of that library to fulfil our needs.